# Restart timer after button is clicked

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem. I have several buttons. I want if the user clicks one button a label should be shown 10 seconds. Now I have the follwing problem. As I said I have several buttons.

[image]

If the user clicks `button1` the `isTagActive == True` should be set for 10 seconds.
This works for me.

But the problem is, if the user clicks `button1` and after 2 seconds `button2` the `isTagActive == True` is also shown only 10 seconds. But it the timer should start from new after `button2` is set. So the the timer counts from the first button, but the should counts from the last button is clicked. How could I change this?

So if the user clicks a button the timer should start from beginning.

Code

```dart
void processClick() async {

    setState(() {
      number++;
    });
    changeActiveStatus();
...
}


  // This is the method
  Future<void> changeActiveStatus() async {
    isTagActive = true;
    if(mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }

    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10), () {
      isTagActive = false;
      if(mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }
    });


  }
```

Comment: Based on the example, does 'isTagActive == true' last for 12 seconds?

Comment: Yes, it should. But the formluation would be wrong. After the second button click the timer should set to 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to reset the time, you could use **debounce**.

```dart
void processClick() async {
  setState(() {
    number++;
  });

  changeActiveStatus();
  ...
}

Timer? _debounce;

// This is the method
Future<void> changeActiveStatus() async {
  isTagActive = true;
  if (mounted) {
    setState(() {});
  }

  if (_debounce?.isActive ?? false) _debounce!.cancel();
  _debounce = Timer(
    const Duration(seconds: 10),
    () {
      isTagActive = false;
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }
    },
  );
}
```